# Why is (d <= 9999 || d > 999) always true?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class asg3 {

    public static int setoriginal() {
        int d=0; 
        int l=0;                                                           
        do {   
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a 4 digit number: ");
            d=input.nextInt();
            if (d<=9999 || d>999) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.err.printf ("You did not enter 4 digits\n");
            }           
            l=l+1;
        } while (l<3);    
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setoriginal();
    }
}
```

when I enter 12345 it works but doesn't seem to work for any other number other than four-digit ones.
any idea of what could be wrong or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) Define "works" - what is this supposed to show the user? 2) Use standard indent formatting

Comment: What do you want to achive with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this condition:

```
if (d <= 9999 || d > 999)
```

For that to evaluate to false, you would have to find a value which is greater than 9999 *and* less than 1000. I think you'll be hard pushed to find such a number...

I suspect you meant:

```
if (d <= 9999 && d > 999)
```

Personally I'd write this as:

```
if (d >= 1000 && d <= 9999)
```

or

```
if (1000 <= d && d <= 9999)
```

In all these versions, you're basically checking that it's greater than or equal to 1000 *and* it's less than or equal to 9999.

Answer (score 2):

Change  `if (d<=9999 || d>999) {break;}` to `if (d<=9999 && d>999) {break;}`

You used an `||` instead of an `&&`. Also consider changing the order so it reads as follows;

```
if (d>=1000 && d<=9999)
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (d<=9999 || d>999) {break;}
```

Every number is either below 9999 or greater than 999; for example, 15 is below 9999 and lets the condition become true. I think, you should replace the || by an && operator.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `||` with `&&`. Should work then :)